# In Java, why does ((A)b).disp() call derived class method disp() instead of base class method disp() ?

Tags: java

I am learning Java, am a beginner... Please help me out finding why this is not working...

In the following program, my aim is to call base class method from main method, without using super keyword in derived class method.

As shown in the code, ((A)b).num in main method works perfectly fine, and ouputs, 100 as expected, but ((A)b).disp() outputs the contents in B's method, instead of A's method.

```
class A
{
    int num=100;

    public void disp()
    {
    System.out.println("Disp() of A:");
    System.out.println(num);
    }

}

class B extends A
{
    int num=200;

    public void disp()
    {
    System.out.println("Disp() of B:");
    super.disp();              //100
    System.out.println( num );  //200
    }

}

class ques
{

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
    B b=new B();

    b.disp();         

    System.out.println();
    ((A)b).disp();                          //doesn't work

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(((A)b).num);         //works
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
Disp() of B:
Disp() of A:
100
200

Disp() of B:
Disp() of A:
100
200
100
```

BUT my expected output was:

```
Disp() of B:
Disp() of A:
100
200


Disp() of A:
100

100
```

Can anyone please help me find the reason for this output.

Why ((A)b).num is working fine and ((A)b).disp() not working as expected...

Moreover this doesn't give compile error.... !! Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: I suggest you read about `Polymorphism` in java. In java, you can assign a Super Class reference to a Sub Class object, so at run time the actual method to be invoked depends on the actual object assigned to the reference, this is the effect of overriding A's disp() in B. You can start [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/polymorphism-in-java/) or [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/polymorphism-in-java.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be this way to preserve the semantics of the derived class.

Imagine A has an integer attribute name *value*, and A.alter() is a method that changes that value. Imagine B extends A and overrides that method, and B gives the additional guarantee that the attribute *value* is always positive. A.alter() might sometimes cause the value to be negative, but B.alter() never will.

If ((A)b).alter() called the A.alter() method on an object of type B, the result could be a B that had a negative value: the guarantee that B is supposed to have would be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Field accesses are resolved at compile-time, while instance (non-static) method calls are always dispatched dynamically. The JVM doesn't care that you are casting `b` to `A`, it will always invoke `disp()` on the actual runtime type of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying something that isn't possible. There is no way to invoke an implementation of a superclass from an instance of the subclass (other than in the subclass via the "super" keyword).

The reason why the num class variable works is, that you cannot override a class variable. What you get in an object of type B is basically two(!) variables named num. One inherited from A (and you access it via the upcast) and one from class B.

Comment: There is a way to implement invocation of super class method (without using 'super') using constructor, checkout answer I have posted in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

As you told aim is to call base class method without using super keyword, here is the solution for that

```
class A {

 A() {
    int num=100;
    System.out.println("Value of  A: ");
    System.out.println(num); //100
 }
}

class B extends A {

B() {
    int num=200;
    System.out.println("Value of B: ");
    System.out.println(num);  //200
 }
}

class ques {

 public static void main(String a[])
 {
    B b=new B();
 }

}
```

O.P.

> Value of A: 100
>
> Value of B: 200

**How does this happened?**

In general cases super keyword is essential if you want to access superclass's method but there is a way you can omit 'SUPER' keyword

- **By using constructor with no parameter** as the constructor initializes methods/variables at the time of declaration, so there is no need for a call.

---

In case if you call a constructor with arguments

For Example

> public A(int i)

Then you compulsorily have to use super keyword, Because then you will have to pass value of type integer here.

Comment: This is because there is an implicit `super()` call at each constructor unless specified otherwise. Quote: "If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments." [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.) So the super call is just not explicit

Comment: Now the concepts are more clear than before, thanks!

Comment: Thank you.... but please read carefully, I have written,  my aim is to "call base class method from main method", without using super keyword in derived class method, here u have used constructor and performed this task, compare the statements "works" and "doesn't work".... in my program... I wanted to know why that wasn't working...

Comment: Yes, Understood your question and also answers :)